# Как правильно настроить Spring Security, чтобы срабатывала при нажатии определенной кнопки?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Использую Vue.js и Java Spring Boot.

Есть проект, в котором надо настроить Spring Security так, чтобы при переходе на другую HTML страницу выкидывалась форма логина.

Если это возможно, конечно - если нет, то подскажите другое решение - хочу закрыть отдельную страницу для входа только через логин.

В (`/**`) в конфиге сделал так, чтобы корень проекта открывался без авторизации, а вот чтобы на следующую страницу перейти, хочу сделать доступ через логин-пароль. Хотелось бы через базовую форму - из коробки, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Сделал `anyRequest().authenticated()` - не срабатывает, хотя на следующей странице производятся `GET` запросы через контроллер, но увы.

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
 }
```

Comment: А зачем там вторая звёздочка?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Давайте опишу - есть две страницы - одна index.html другая board.html -  возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии button для перехода с index на board выскакивала форма логина из spring security? Как это сделать в js коде я знаю но мне надо через секуру спрингаю. Для чего это? Хочу сделать закрытую страницу только для определенных лиц - модераторов. Со страницы board идет запрос "/moderation" к контроллеру для подтягивания сообщений, требующих модерацию, ну и соответственно на этой странице они отображаются. Как то так, надеюсь понятно обьяснил, старался)

Comment: На index.html отображаются только принятые сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Во первых на форму логина надо добавить адрес и разрешения

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

Во вторых, с учётом коментария, требуются особые права на  "/moderation". Это можно осуществить добавлением роли (например ADMIN):

```
.authorizeRequests() 
  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()       
  .antMatchers("/moderation/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")                    
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Вот [пример](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/), показывающий как можно использовать Spring Security для вэб-приложения.

Comment: Я сделал кастомную форму логина - login.html, контроллер "/login", надо написать login.js для связи с контроллером, естественно loginPage().disable() сделал. Не могу найти годноту по vue js для Login.js

Comment: Тогда пиши контроллер на js.  Зачем тебе spring?

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем сделал так, отпраляю username и password напрямую с кастомной login.html на контроллер - дальше в сервисе сопоставляю пароли, в моем случае через bcryptpasswordencoder.matches, дальше если true - то контроллер возвращает другую html страницу,  к которой нужен доступ через login, в противном случае - возврат на прежнюю страницу с ошибкой.