# Ошибочное перенаправление GET запроса (контроллером?) на неправильную HTML страницу

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-jpa

Делаю **spring-security-mvc-jpa** проектик с регистрацией с бд **mysql**, bootstrap для кнопочек и **thymeleaf** для страниц.

**Проблема:**

`GET` запрос `http://localhost:8080/registration` перенаправляется на не созданную мной страницу login.html из бутстрапа по умолчанию. Страница регистрации (моя) со статусом в хроме 302. Страница логин и ее стили (которую я не создавал) - 200.
При этом предпросмотр в INTELLIJ - отображает нужную страницу правильно.

Далее я покажу `application.properties`. `registration.html` и контроллер, и что уже попробовано.

**Это контроллер:**

```
package com.example.springsecurityjpa.web;
import com.example.springsecurityjpa.services.UserService;
import com.example.springsecurityjpa.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class  UserRegistrationController {
    private UserService userService;

    public UserRegistrationController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto() {
        return new UserRegistrationDto();
    }
    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "registration";
    }
    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
        userService.save(registrationDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

**Это `application.properties`:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/securitydemo?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*********
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
server.port=8080
```

**Это HTML страница регистрации:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta url="http://localhost:8085/registration">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet"-->
          <!--href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
          <!--integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"-->
          <!--crossorigin="anonymous">-->
</head>
<body>

<!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Registration and
                Login Module</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<br>
<br>
<!-- Create HTML registration form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <!-- success message -->
            <div th:if="${param.success}">
                <div class="alert alert-info">You've successfully registered!</div>
            </div>

            <h1>Registration</h1>

            <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="firstName"> First Name </label>
                    <input id="firstName" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}"
                           required autofocus="autofocus" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="lastName"> Last Name </label> <input
                        id="lastName" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}"
                        required autofocus="autofocus" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label> <input
                        id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required
                        autofocus="autofocus" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label> <input
                        id="password" class="form-control" type="password"
                        th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                    <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login
                                here</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<head/>
```

**Не помогло:**

1. ```
   #server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
   #server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
   ```
2. Проверить (скопипастить) название страницы регистрации чтобы исключить ошибку (при ошибке в названии контроллер может возвращать что-то по умолчанию.
3. Подключать разные версии Bootstrap (3-4).
4. Добавить в базу хотя бы одну запись. Находил пост, что если база абсолютно пустая - могут быть сбои.
5. Проверен файл host - там нет ограничений.

Comment: Где конфигурация по безопасности?

Comment: @RomanC Вы оказались правы. Дело в отсутсвующем конфиге. Балбес на ютубе которого я смотрел при монтаже умудрился при монтаже пропустить этот кусок. Респект в общем. Если вам нужны плюсики - напишите ваш ответ - в поле ответа. Поставим на него галочку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенаправление происходит потому, что требуется аундетийикация для ресурса `"/registration"`.  Если конфигурация вэб-секюрити выглядит так например [Spring Boot Security Authentication with JPA, Hibernate and MySQL](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-security-authentication-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql):

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
```

то перенаправление на форму логина происходит автоматически. Для того чтобы этого не происходило надо добавить разрешения следующим образом (примерно как это делал в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1186682/204920) ответе):

```
http.authorizeRequests() 
  .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
```